# Pi Zero, is it possible to program two GPIO output pins to make/break continuity between them?

Tags: switches

Just a simple analog contact closure. No output voltage needed. I know this can be done with a relay, but wondering if I can simply use two pins as there will be no load on the circuit. Also, I am an idiot and this may be a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If they are both inputs they will have random voltages (randomly high or low).

If they are both outputs they will either be both high, both low, or one high one low (a recipe for damage).

If one is an input and the other is an output the input will have the voltage set at the output.

Comment: high quality answer. i just learned important stuff. thank you.